Keycloak v25 - enable Exchange-token
Im using Keycloak 25.
Im using python keycloak to use keycloak API.
I've managed to enable Impersonation from web interface but I need to impersonate user by api using token echange.
The official page has differente screenshot and I cant find section where enable token_exchange.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_token-exchange

This is the method sign in KeycloakOpenID
def exchange_token(
        self,
        token: str,
        audience: Optional[str] = None,
        subject: Optional[str] = None,
        subject_token_type: Optional[str] = None,
        subject_issuer: Optional[str] = None,
        requested_issuer: Optional[str] = None,
        requested_token_type: str = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token",
        scope: str = "openid",
    ) -> dict:
        """Exchange user token.

        Use a token to obtain an entirely different token. See
        https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_token-exchange

This is the error I get:
keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakPostError: 400: b'{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Unsupported grant_type"}'


I have the same issue you can check :
https://www.keycloak.org/server/features#:~:text=Multi%2Dsite%20support-,Preview%20features,-Preview%20features%20are
I just restart my keycloak environnement and add KC_FEATURES=token-exchange to enabled the feature.
(I use chart helm to deploy)
containers:
 - name: my_container_name    
   image: "quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:{{ .Values.KC_version }}"
      command:
        - /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh
        - start
      env:
        ....
        - name: KC_FEATURES
          value: token-exchange

